# Could Huawei AppGallery Connect API be used with specific project?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

A connect API client is created using AGC Console [Connect API](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html#/ups/9249519184595983258) option. When creating the client, a project is selected as well to limit the scope of access. Credentials are created without problem.

Obtained access token by using POST to this [AGC](https://connect-api.cloud.huawei.com/api/oauth2/v1/token) URL, then passed the token to [publishing API](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-appid-list_v2), Connect API server returned 403 error code when using GET method to query the API. Checking the document, there is mention of setting the project to N/A to avoid the error.

My question is why the project could not be set here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect API is team-level access. It is valid for all projects under the account ID which created the connect API client. To use connect API, a project should always be set to N/A.

The project would be specified when server SDK is used in a project.

Answer (score 0):

The value of project must be set to N/A because the Connect API requires some account-level permissions. If an application is restricted, the permissions cannot be obtained. Therefore, you cannot set a specific application.